# tcp: what if a new SYN request is sent to an existing connection in LAST_ACK state?

Tags: linux, tcp

My web server recently gets a little high retransmission rate. After capturing some packages, I see quite a lot packages in the following sequence:
[image]

when client sends SYNC request to my server, it doesn't responses with SYN+ACK. instead, it just return ACK, and retransimits a FIN+ACK. So I suspect the client is behind NAT, and a new SYN request is sent to an exsiting connection in LAST_ACK state, so a new connection cannot be established.

Would you please provide some guidance on how to solve this from the server side？ Thanks!

Comment: First suspect a misbehaving firewall.

Comment: Are you sure that all of those packets are from the same TCP stream? The Sequence numbers not match up.

Comment: @MarkoPolo, I used the "follow tcp stream" in wireshark to get the packets in the screenshot.

Comment: You will need to take a packet capture from server side and client side to figure out which side of the communication is causing the issue.